# How do I install Fira Code to R-Studio on Windows?

Tags: rstudio, ligature

According to the R-Studio blog, R-Studio 1.1+ now supports [ligatures](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/09/13/rstudio-v1.1---the-little-things/).

I installed R-Studio version 1.1.442 on Windows.

According to the [R-Studio blog](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/09/13/rstudio-v1.1---the-little-things/), and the Fira Code project [instructions](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/RStudio-instructions), I should be able to select Fira as follows:

> - Go to Tools > Global Options > Appearance
> - Select "Fira Code" as Editor Font, and check "Use Ligatures".
> - Hit "OK" and enjoy

[image]

I do not have the ability to select 'Fira Code.'

[image: Click for screenshot of menu without Fira Code]

I downloaded the most recent [Fira Code release](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/releases), and noticed a TTF folder in the zip.

[image: Click for screenssh of the TTF folder in the Fira Code Release Zip]

Where do I install the Fira Code font so that I can use Fira Code on R-Studio (Windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you still find this helpful. Try installing the `.otf` files instead.

[image]

Try restarting Rstudio, or if that does not work, try restarting your computer. Fira Code should now appear as an option in Editor Font.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with a similar problem, but re-starting R Studio did the trick for me. I'm posting this in case anybody else deals with something similar